# How can I parse both Java and C++ in Eclipse?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, parsing

On the Eclipse homepage, I see two versions -- Eclipse for C++ developers and Eclipse for Java developers.  I'm working on a project that combines both Java and native C++ code.  I am using the Java version, and when I open one of the C++ files, not only is it not parsed, but it opens the file in an external editor.  I'm probably missing something simple, but how do I get Eclipse to work with both types of source files?  Is there a combined Eclipse package for this?  Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to toggle the perspective when you're working on a Java or a C++ file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Eclipse is fully plugin based. Just go to *Help -> Install new Software* and select the Indigo (or whatever version you are using) update site. Then go to *Programming languages* and select the C/C++ tools you want to install. The different downloads from the Eclipse website are basically just preconfigured plugin bundles and you can always add anything you are missing from the plugin manager.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. For some reason when I right click on a symbol in a cpp file and search for references, or I control-click on a symbol, it doesn't find anything.  Is there a way to force a reparse of _just_ the cpp code in the project, so as to not have to reparse the java part?

Comment: Hm, I really recommend splitting the Java part and the C++ part into two different eclipse projects. I don't think that it will work properly otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the missing functionality with adding the appropriate plugins.

http://eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the C++ views from a Java version of Eclipse, the same way you would download any packages. They are two different 'views' though so I don't think you can look at code for both in the same project view.

This explains it http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/