# Enhance C++ Eclipse with Java

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, user-interface, ubuntu

I use Eclipse Mars for C/C++ on Ubuntu. Now I must use Java. I reading on how to [install Java on Eclipse](http://codeyarns.com/2014/12/09/how-to-install-java-to-eclipse-cdt/), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853450/install-eclipse-jdt-on-top-of-cdt) as well as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175296/how-can-i-parse-both-java-and-c-in-eclipse). It is obvious that I have to click on Help, but I can't find it in Eclipse, thus I am asking for help! :)

[image]

Or maybe is there a way to activate Help via terminal or something?

Comment: Well that's weird. And what happens if you press Alt+H?

Comment: @Tunaki yes! I am getting the File Edit Source ... menu showing (it does not when mouse is not there). I will check back in 3 hours. I have to go now!

Comment: Apparently you can disable that: Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective... (a new window) Menu visibility (tab) > tick "Help"

Comment: @zapl Help was ticked. I chose reset the Perspective and it appeared! You helped. What should I do with the question now?

Comment: Make a nice answer that explains what you did and accept it

Comment: @zapl allow me to say that you should answer the question, because your comment triggered the solution. Moreover I will be able to accept it now and not after 2 days ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu can be customized as part of the [perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm)

To get it to show, the two options are

1. *Reset* the entire perspective. `Help` should be visible by default in every one but resetting will reset every customization done to the perspective.

   - this can be done either through `Preferences`, `General` > `Perspectives` via the `Revert` button
   - or via the menu for the current perspective: `Window` > `Perspective` > `Reset Perspective...`
2. *Adjust* the perspective

   - `Window` > `Perspective` > `Customize Perspective...`
   - In the new window that appears in the `Menu Visibility` tab is the `Help` entry which is probably invisible.